# Must an object extend NSObject to be a strong reference inside a block?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

From Apple's [Blocks Programming Topics: Blocks and Variables](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1)

> **Objective-C Objects**
>   When a block is copied, it creates strong references to object variables used within the block.

What if the object doesn't extend from NSObject? Is that relevant?

e.g. Given a property of

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) FooBlock fooBlock;
```

is the following

```
-(void)foo:(NSObject<Foo>*)foo
{
    self.fooBlock = ^(){
        [foo bar];
    };
}
```

any different to

```
-(void)foo:(id<Foo>)foo
{
    self.fooBlock = ^(){
        [foo bar];
    };
}
```

Comment: What object **doesn't** extend `NSObject`?

Comment: Any object you choose its class not to?

Comment: And you have written a class that doesn't extend `NSObject`?

Comment: -retain is sent to all the object variables captured by block - if you  created  custom class, you should get unrecognized selector error or something even worse

Comment: @trojanfoe NSProxy comes in mind. Do you think the question does not stand?

Comment: I think it's more theoretical than practical, given you don't appear to be using classes that don't subclass `NSObject` anyway.  It therefore probably belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com more than SO.

Comment: Would say that @OladyaKane's comment looks like an acceptable answer. Wouldn't you agree @trojanfoe? If so, Oladya can you please add it?

Comment: NSProxy implements the NSObject **protocol** even though it doesn't inherit from NSObject....

Answer (score 2):

Note that the documentation says *object* variables, not *NSOjbect* variables.  All Objective-C objects are treated the same in this context, regardless of their base class.

As others have pointed out, you need only ensure that your object responds to the usual memory management selectors - in particular retain and release.

Tangentially, keep in mind that deriving from a base class other than NSObject is usually unwise.  It's possible (e.g. NSProxy) but it can get very complicated very fast.  Ensure you have a good reason to do so.

Comment: By object variables assume you mean *objc_object* type, which the only requirement is to have a *Class isa*. So how does that relate to creating a strong reference?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Are you unclear on what a strong reference is?  It just means the block sends -retain to the object when the block is created, and -release to it when the block is destroyed.